# JQuery in Firefox Addon causes multiple warnings

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using jquery within a firefox addon, but i keep getting tons of warning messages like below:

```
                     anonymous function does not always return a value
System JS : WARNING resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/use
rs/usernameremoved/appdata/local/temp/tmprpnucw.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-I3FWz29roUS
8UA@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.
js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-i
3fwz29rous8ua-at-jetpack/addon-name-removed/data/jquery.js:2435
```

Can you please let me know how can i ignore these errors? I can't find my console logs or errors because of them...

Jquery is included like this:

```
contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js"),
self.data.url("zde.js"),
self.data.url("zdf.js")],
contentStyleFile: self.data.url("zd.css"),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings are a result of the [`javascript.options.strict`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/) (can be turned off and on again in about:config). Unfortunately, as far as I know, these warnings cannot be turned off on a file-by-file (or URI-by-URI) basis.

It appears that [the SDK turns on](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/d3b7ef5109fa8adb65331007ccd2cb0c9a986baf/python-lib/cuddlefish/prefs.py) this preference by default (in a normal browser it is turned off by default). There doesn't seem to be a way to change that via command line switches, so you'd have to locally patch the linked file in your copy of the SDK.

Those are valid warnings, but as you noted, pretty useless when it comes to third-party library code that you cannot fix anyway.

Comment: Oh yes, it works! Great, but still i have to modify it within about:config every each time i modify my code. Do you know maybe where could i make it "off" by default when running cfx run?

Comment: I already answered that: You need to patch the one python file I linked in the SDK itself.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed annoying. You can disable it from within your extension (for dev. only) as follows:

```
require("sdk/preferences/service").set("javascript.options.strict", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `cfx run` to test your application. Sadly the direct console output is that cluttered and to my knowledge there isn't a way to only show the relevant logs of your extension.

If you are specifically interested in the `console.log()` and `console.error()`s, I recommend you use the [Browser Console](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/the-browser-console/). There you can hide all output except for the Logging events.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far, but i still can't get the error message with console.error() if the code fails before executing it.